# MySQL moving average - 4 weeks

Tags: mysql, moving-average

I've been reading several posts regarding estimating moving average in a mysql query, however its seems that my situation is slightly more difficult as the table don't contain a column that i want to calculate the average of. I need to count the numbers of rows for each group, and present the moving average of that group.

I basically have only one column of relevance in the table, and that is a DATETIME column. The table can contain several rows with the same date. I want to group the table by YEARWEEK and COUNT(*) the numbers of rows for each YEARWEEK-group. This is easy, the difficult part is to also calculate the moving 4-week average in addition

```
+-------------+
| DatoLagtTil |
+-------------+
| 2012-11-01  |
| 2012-10-25  |
| 2012-10-25  |
| 2012-10-11  |
| 2012-10-04  |
| ...         |
| ...         |
| ...         |
| ...         |
+-------------+
```

This is the output table that I am looking to create - the 4 week (YEARWEEK) moving average is the difficult part (Note: The example below is not based on the sample data above)

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| YEARWEEK   | COUNT      | m_average |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 201201     |     5      |     5     |
| 201202     |     10     |     7.5   |  
| 201203     |     5      |     6.6   |
| 201204     |     15     |     8.8   | 
| 201205     |     10     |     10    |
| 201206     |     5      |     8.8   |
| 201207     |     5      |     8.8   |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

I've found several good sources explaining how to calculate moving average, however I can't get them to work in my case. I'm hoping you guys can help.

Thanks

---Status update---

Been trying a few solutions since I posted this question. I feel that I'm getting closer, but there are still something essential missing.

With the query below I get no errors, however I'm getting too high a Count(k.DatoLagtTil) and the same AVG(cnt) for all YEARWEEK-groups... I do believe this has to do with there WHERE clause I'm using

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(k.DatoLagtTil), COUNT(k.DatoLagtTil), AVG(cnt)
  FROM  Kunder_db k, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM Kunder_db
         WHERE YEARWEEK(DatoLagtTil) BETWEEN YEARWEEK(DatoLagtTil) - 3 AND YEARWEEK(DatoLagtTil)
        GROUP BY YEARWEEK(DatoLagtTil)) x
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(k.DatoLagtTil)
```

Comment: Where there are no records for a week within the previous 4, shouldn't that week still be included (with an implied count of 0) in the moving average?  That is, in your example, shouldn't `201201` have an average of 1.25, `201202` have 3.75, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join the count query with your table again, using a suitable range criterion:

```
SELECT   t.yearweek,
         t.count,
         COUNT(*) / 4 AS m_average

FROM     my_table JOIN (
  SELECT   YEARWEEK(DatoLagtTil) AS yearweek,
           COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM     my_table
  GROUP BY yearweek
) t ON t.yearweek BETWEEN YEARWEEK(DatoLagtTil)
                      AND YEARWEEK(DatoLagtTil + INTERVAL 3 week)

GROUP BY t.yearweek
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ca76/1/0).

Comment: That seemed to work really well. I'll test it a bit further, but it seems spot on :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In mysql 8 [window function frame](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html) can be used to obtain the averages.

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(k.DatoLagtTil) as YRWK, count(*), AVG(count(*)) OVER (ORDER BY YEARWEEK(k.DatoLagtTil) ROWS 3 PRECEDING) as m_average
FROM Kunder_db
GROUP BY YRWK
```

This calculates the average of the current row and 3 preceding rows.